# Azure App Service manage task with Action "Swap Slots" in Pipelines\Releases works even source slot has Unhealthy status

Tags: azure-web-app-service, containers, health-monitoring, health-check, blue-green-deployment

I have App Service plan with pricing Standard S1. There is App Service for container with 2 slots (production and slot). Deployed container has endpoint /health and doesn’t have endpoint /healthcheck. When I set “Health check” path as “/healthcheck” (for testing purposes) for non production slot I see that it has Unhealthy state and it's correct:

[AppService HealthCheck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvHAf.png)

[Unhealthy Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG0xL.png)

After that I run my release which has next steps:

[Pipeline tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub8iX.png)

Tasks in YAML view:

[AppService Deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xucNB.png)

[Swap Slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlHxn.png)

And I have success result, but it shouldn’t be.
[Pipeline Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZemd.png)

Even I use variables described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#specify-custom-warm-up for deployment slot:
WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH=“/healthcheck”
WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_STATUSES=“200”
I see that warming up was success, but my container doesn’t have endpoint “/healthcheck”

My goal to do pipeline which doesn’t do swap if deployment slot after deploy has Unhealthy state.